Load Balancing in EVPN VXLAN Based Fabric via EVPN Route Type 1
There is a confusion with respect to EVPN Route Type 1. Can someone clarify that which EVPN Route Type 1 (AD per ES or AD per EVI) is used for load balancing?
Though it sound trivial that EVPN AD per EVI (Aliasing) is used for load balancing. EVPN route type 1 per EVI is advertised in EVPN VXLAN Bridge Overlay (BO) Fabric or Edge Routing & Bridging Fabric (ERB) where end host is dual homed to 2 x LEAFs.
However , in case of CRB (Centrally Routed & Bridging ) with routing on SPINEs and VGA address defined on IRB interface there is no EVPN AD Route Type 1 per EVI. There is only EVPN AD Route Type 1 per ES from both SPINEs , yet the LEAFs are able to load balance the traffic destined to VGA address on SPINEs.
For example , there is no LAG interface (hence no ESI) defined on SPINEs in CRB based Fabric , yet we do see the following output on LEAFs (output is taken from Juniper documentation for brevity)

ESI Resolving to VTEPs in Juniper 
Hence from functionality of EVPN route type 1 AD , which one is used for load balancing ? Is it EVPN AD per EVI or EVPN AD per ESI?
